# Count files in folder and subfolders, exlucing folders with string

Tags: vba

Given a folder tree:

```
c:\example\
c:\example\2014-01-01\
c:\example\2014-01-01\Entered\
c:\example\2014-01-02\
c:\example\2014-01-02\Entered
etc.
```

I want to count the PDF files in the tree, but excluding any in the "Entered\" subfolders.

Is this possible even with VBA? Ultimately this count needs to be spit out onto an excel sheet.

Comment: It's possible, but I suggest posting your code. People are more likely to help if they see you've done some work towards your problem already. For starters, look into the Dir() function and recursion.

Comment: I haven't gotten to the point where I'm messing with any code yet. Still trying to get my bearings on the nuances of VBA, if I understand the easiest way to do this will be to count every file in all folders (including "entered" folders) as a variable and then subtract the number of files found in each "entered" folder.

Comment: Check out: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?139-Count-Files-(with-a-specific-extension-or-not)-in-a-folder-and-subfolders There's a pretty comprehensive example that you should be able to modify to suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, this should be relatively simple using the FileSystemObject of the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkx696eh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). You'll want to recursively loop through all files in a given folder and look at the name attribute of the file object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy all the code in an Excel-VBA Module. If you want to use a button then you should use `CntFiles()` on the button. But if you don't want to use a button then you can use `fCount(strPath)` as a formula on the Worksheet i.e `=fCount("your-path")`, the parameter is String so make it double-quoted when using on Worksheet.

```
Function fCount(strPath)
    Dim fCnt As Integer
    fCnt = ShowFolderList(strPath)
    fCount = fCnt
End Function

Sub CntFiles()
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "A:\Asif\Answers\abc"
    ShowFolderList (strPath)
End Sub

Function ShowFolderList(Path)
    Dim fso, folder, subFlds, fld
    Dim tFiles As Integer

    tFiles = ShowFilesList(Path)

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(Path)
    Set subFlds = folder.SubFolders

    For Each fld In subFlds
        If fld.Name = "Entered" Then
            GoTo SkipFld:
        Else
            Path = fld.Path
            tFiles = tFiles + ShowFilesList(Path)
        End If
SkipFld:
    Next

    'MsgBox tFiles & " files"
    ShowFolderList = tFiles
End Function

Function ShowFilesList(folderspec)
   Dim fso, f, f1, fc, s
   Dim Cnt As Integer

   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   Set f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec)
   Set fc = f.Files

        For Each f1 In fc

            If GetAnExtension(f1) = "pdf" Then
                Cnt = Cnt + 1
            Else

            End If

        Next

   ShowFilesList = Cnt
End Function

Function GetAnExtension(DriveSpec)
   Dim fso
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   GetAnExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(DriveSpec)
End Function
```

This code will count all the files in the specified folder as well as sub-folders excluding folder named "Entered" as you specified.

Comment: Much appreciated! I made some changes to suit this specific application, but this code was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This code gives you a nice overview in an excel sheet:

```
Sub start()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim FolderName As String
Sheets("fldr").Select
Cells(1, 1).Value = 2
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
    On Error Resume Next
    FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
ListFolders (FolderName)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done" & vbCrLf & "Total files found: " & Cells(1, 1).Value
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Source"
Cells(1, 2).Value = "Folder"
Cells(1, 3).Value = "Subfolder"
Cells(1, 4).Value = "FileCount"
End Sub

Sub ListFolders(Fldr As String)
Dim fs
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fl1
    Set fl1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fl2
    Set fl2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fl1 = fs.GetFolder(Fldr)
For Each fl2 In fl1.SubFolders
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 1).Value = Replace(Fldr, fl1.Name, "")
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 2).Value = fl1.Name
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 3).Value = fl2.Name
    Cells(Cells(1, 1).Value, 4).Value = CountFiles(Fldr & "\" & fl2.Name)
    Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value + 1
    ListFolders fl2.Path
Next
End Sub

Function CountFiles(Fldr As String)
Dim fso As Object
Dim objFiles As Object
Dim obj As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFiles = fso.GetFolder(Fldr).Files
CountFiles = objFiles.Count
Set objFiles = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set obj = Nothing
End Function
```