# Access VBA Count Specific Kind of Files in a Folder

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

For example, I have following files in a folder

aaa001.txt

aaa002.txt

aaa003.txt

bbb001.txt

bbb002.txt

...

Is there any way I can count the number of files starting with "aaa" in this folder?

I can do `Dir("*\aaa*.txt")` in a loop while counting. But I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Even though it is counting as you are, this answer details out some good code http://stackoverflow.com/a/22630255/1504882

Comment: Dir I believe is the way to go.  Another resource here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba.  If its running too slowly, maybe post what code you have so far, the issue might be the way it is setup rather than the function being expensive

Comment: `dir aaa*.*|findstr /i /c:"File(s)"`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

No. `Dir` is simple and as fast as can be.